# `will-change: opacity` doesn't create new stacking context

Tags: html, css, opacity, will-change, stacking-context

in [MDN web docs it is mentioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) that stacking context is formed in these scenarios:

6. Element with a opacity value less than 1
7. Element with a `will-change` value specifying any property that would create a stacking context on non-initial value

but when I set `will-change` to `opacity` (non-initial value of less than 1) the stacking doesn't work as expected (blue div below red one), see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9an8L4m/19/)

some other scenarios works as expected like; blue div above red one (links to fiddles)

2. [Element with a position value absolute or relative and z-index value other than auto](https://jsfiddle.net/h9an8L4m/18/)
3. [Element that is a child of a grid container, with z-index value other than auto](https://jsfiddle.net/h9an8L4m/17/)

what am I doing wrong, and is there any other way to make stacking context works as expected

I'm asking because sometime I can't change the position to relative as this will affect the absolute children of that element

Answer (score 1):

The stacking (creation of a new layer) is actually working.

[image]

The problem is that `z-index` works only for:

- Positioned elements (`absolute`, `relative`, `fixed`, `sticky`).
- Children elements of a `flex` container.

No matter if you set `z-index: 30`, at the end it will remain at its default value, `auto`.